# SEVERE: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a Oracle function which returns sys_refcursor which is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SCOTT.getemployees
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
   o_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN o_cursor FOR
      SELECT EMPNO,
             ENAME,
             JOB,
             MGR,
             HIREDATE,
             SAL,
             COMM,
             DEPTNO
        FROM emp;   
   RETURN o_cursor;
END;
/
```

In my Entity class I have declared as

```
@Entity
    @javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery(name = "getEmp", 
    query = "{ ? = call getemployees }", resultClass = Employees.class, hints = {
    @javax.persistence.QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") })
    @Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
    public class Employees {
```

In DAO I have

```
@Inject
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Employees> getEmployees() {

        List query = new ArrayList<Employees>();
         try{
         query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .getNamedQuery("getEmp").list();
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("exception "+e.getMessage());
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return query;
    }
```

When I run I am getting exception, what could be the reason for this?

> INFO: Hibernate: { ? = call getemployees }
>       SEVERE: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
>           at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)

Comment: Please stop tagging JPA questions with JSF. JPA problems (wherein you retrieve an exception from `javax.persistence` or JPA implementation specific package like `org.hibernate`) have nothing to do with JSF. JSF is just frontend MVC framework. You'd have exactly the same problem when using this JPA code together with plain JSP/Servlet, or Spring MVC, or Struts 2, or Wicket, or even a Swing frontend, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue.

Database table columns which are defined as numbers are declared as `int` in Entity class. 
I have changed those to `Integer` and problem got resolved.

```
private Integer deptNo;

public Integer getDeptNo() {
        return deptNo;
    }

    public void setDeptNo(Integer deptNo) {
        this.deptNo = deptNo;
    }
```